# What is resaon for deploying package.json to heroku?

Tags: heroku

i'm trying to upload a javascript nodejs project to Heroku. Localhost works perfectly but when i try to upload it gives me a:

> unable to parse error at :
>   The Error Message : Unmatched '}' at line 16, column 1

Full Json file:

```
{
    "name": "reactbot",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "React bot for webpage",
    "main": "index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.16.2",
        "npm": "6.14.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "Ruhul",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your message so that people can help you better. Specifically format the error block of the message and try to give a little more context to your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show more context for that error message. Do you see it at build time, or runtime?

Comment: -----> Node.js app detected
parse error: Unmatched '}' at line 16, column 1
 !     Unable to parse package.json
-----> Build failed
We're sorry this build is failing!
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: @M.M.RuhulAmin, are you _entirely sure_ that you have committed and deployed the exact content you're showing us here? That message doesn't seem to match what we're seeing.

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this platform. Thank your for your valuable comment @Chris Yes, im facing at build time. While pushing the code to Heroku repository for deploying the app, at the final step in deployment. i.e. in the terminal using the command 'git push Heroku master' I actually facing the following error message (copied from error log):
-----> Node.js app detected
parse error: Unmatched '}' at line 16, column 1
 !     Unable to parse package.json
-----> Build failed
We're sorry this build is failing! 
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But line 16, column 1 in the content you're showing us is the beginning of the line containing your `express` dependency, which doesn't contain a `}`. It is common that error messages like this actually reflect a problem on the previous line, but the previous line doesn't contain `}` either. I suspect you're actually using some other `package.json`. The file you're showing us is in the root of your repository? It has been committed as shown?

Answer (score -1):

The package.json file defines the dependencies that should be installed with your application.

> Be sure to use the correct JSON format.

e.g.

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This example is so cool.",
  "main": "web.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "jane-doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.9.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  }
}
```

Comment: What part of the JSON OP shows in their question is invalid? It looks fine to me, and it passes an online linter. Please read [answer].

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much. All the necessary dependencies installed namely Git, Express etc.

Comment: @Chris as the error shows apparently it is the format of the json problem.